# gitlab-ci can't find config/database.yml, although it's not supposed to exist in my repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to create gitlab-ci file for my Rails project.

Here's a part of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -yqq nodejs libmysqlclient-dev
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
  - bundle install --jobs $(nproc) "${FLAGS[@]}"
  - bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load
  - bundle exec rake db:migrate --quiet
```

And the error is:

```
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
```

On my local machine and server the files config/database.yml are present.

"config/database.yml" doesn't exist *in the repo* and isn't supposed too. It's added in gitignore

**Only the default `config/database.example.yml` exists in my repo. And it doesn't contain the real credentials of my db.**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Put on that script to copy the `.example.yml` to `database.yml` and use the environment variables to set the config: 
   e.g:

   ```
   production:
         username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
         host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
         etc...
   ```
2. create a script to generate this file for you with data hardcoded or from the environment and call on `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: what env. variables will it read in #1 given that it's executed on gitlab? how would I create env variables on gitlab with my db credentials?

Comment: Documentation is your close friend! https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables enjoy :D